# ajax to controller

Tags: hibernate, spring

I want json array or ajax code for parse data jsp to controller

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are missing dbcp in your classpath:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

see http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/ for the correct version

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have included commons-dbcp as a dependency in your pom file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [commons-dbcp-1.4.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar) (or other version) into WAR classpath. This can be done by either putting this JAR file inside your WAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` directory or simply by copying it to Tomcat `/lib` directory. Restart and it should work.